# Creating cumulative matrix which accounts for column start points

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, cumsum

I have a simple example matrix as follows: (The actual matrix I'm working on is 674x11 and is not simply all '1' elements).

```
a = 

    1 1 1 NaN NaN
    1 1 1 NaN NaN
    1 1 1 1 NaN
    1 1 1 1 1 
    1 1 1 1 1
```

I want to create a cumulative matrix which accounts for the fact that numeric elements start in each column at different rows. I want to achieve this by replacing the NaN value above the first numeric element in each column with the mean of that row.

So instead of:

```
cumsum(a)=

    1 1 1 NaN NaN
    2 2 2 NaN NaN
    3 3 3 1 NaN
    4 4 4 2 1
    5 5 5 3 2
```

what I want to achieve is:

```
cumsum(a) = 

    1 1 1 NaN NaN
    2 2 2 2 NaN
    3 3 3 3 3  
    4 4 4 4 4
    5 5 5 5 5
```

where element (2,4) is the mean of a(2,1:3) and element (3,5) is the mean of a(3,1:4).

Comment: Do you want to replace *all* `NaN` values in the output?

Comment: There is a problem in your example. Shouldn't  it be `element (2,4) is the mean of cumsum(a)(2,1:3)`?

Comment: Actually, on thinking through the problem, you are correct. Element (2,4) should be the mean of cumsum(a) (2,1:3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the mean of each row (ignoring the `NaN` values) by using `nanmean`. We can then use `find` to identify the row in which each `NaN` is and replace the values with the mean of that row. Then we can follow that up with the `cumsum` operation

```
% Get the rows of each NaN value
bool = isnan(a);
[row,col] = find(bool);

% Compute the mean value of each row
rowmeans = nanmean(a, 2);

% Replace the NaN values with their row means
a(bool) = rowmeans(row);

% Perform the cumulative sum
result = cumsum(a);
```

If you want to leave the initial `NaN` values as `NaN` values afterwards, then you can follow it up with

```
result(bool) = NaN;
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks very much!